# Sheet to sheet multiple cell comparison

Tags: excel, vba, date, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to create a code that will compare the first column (Dates) on sheet8 with the first column (Dates) on sheet7. In addition, I have to compare the 2nd columns on each sheet (Shift). Once the program hits the correct shift and date, I need to copy and paste some certain data located on sheet7 to sheet8. I've searched quite a bit on it and can't seem to find the correct answer. (Note: somewhat new to vba and self taught so forgive me for any mistakes in code).

```
enter code here
Option Explicit
Sub GrabKPI()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim date1 As Date, date2 As Date
Dim shift1 As Integer, shift2 As Integer
date1 = Sheets("Sheet8").Range("A" & i)
date2 = Sheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & j)
shift1 = Sheets("Sheet8").Range("B" & i)
shift2 = Sheets("Sheet7").Range("B" & j)

For i = 2 To 1697
If date1 = date2 Then
    If shift1 = shift2 Then
        Sheets("Sheet7").Activate
        Range("C" & j, "F" & j).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet8").Activate
        Range("I" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        j = j + 1
    Else: j = j + 1
    End If
Else: j = j + 1
End If
i = i + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

Right now, I get the error "Application-defined or object-defined error" referring to the date1 and date2 statements. However I tried using this general code with a different set up and it would run but nothing would happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get that error is that you're trying to access a `Range` that doesn't exist. Basically:

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
```

will declare `i` and `j` as Integer and assign them the default value of `0`. Some lines after, you do:

```
date1 = Sheets("Sheet8").Range("A" & i)
date2 = Sheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & j)
```

Being `i` and `j` equal to `0`, you're trying to access the `Range("A0")` of the two sheets. This object doesn't exist, so you get an `Application-defined or object-defined error`. If the values are in the ranges `Range("A1")` of the two sheets, consider assigning correctly the two values of `i = 1` and `j=1` before running the `date1` and `date2` statements. This will solve your `1004 error`. As for the effectiveness of the rest of the code, you will need to debug basing on your own data to figure out where the coding inconsistency lies.

Comment: That got past the first problem however it still runs and doesn't do anything, it seems that it's not even performing an iteration within the for loop

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because you are comparing two ranges.  Try changing date1 and date2 to `Sheets("Sheet").Range("B" $ i).value` (add '.value' at the end).  That might help.  If not, then change the declarations for date1 and date2 to String, instead of Date.

Comment: When you set a variable of type "Date" equal to a Range, you're accessing the value property so you don't need to specify ".value" (it might be just for elegance purpose). Moreover, if there's a date in the range, it's not by converting it in string that the equality is going to be reached, the values keep on being different anyway.

Comment: Yeah I tried both and still stuck on that. I've dim(med) dates before and had them work so I'm not sure what I necessarily did differently this time. Appreciate the answer though!